# what is the n queens complexity time by Back Tracking Method?

Tags: time-complexity, tracking, back, n-queens

[image]

What is the n queens complexity time by *Back Tracking* Method?
and what is the count of Queens Position?

With below algorithm :

```
void queens (index i)
{
    index j;
    if (promising(i))
        if (i == n)
            cout << col[1] through col[n];
        else
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                col[i + 1] = j;
                queens(i + 1);
            }
}

bool promising (index i)
{
    index k;
    bool Switch;
    k = 1;
    Switch = true ;
    while (k < i && switch) {
        if (col[i] == col[k] || abs(col[i] – col[k] == i - k))
            switch = false;
        k++;
    }
    return Switch;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is your thinking on the problem? Do you have a guess or any intuition?

Comment: i want to know n queens complexity time by Back Tracking Method

Comment: If you want help with the problem that's great, but please show us how you've tried to solve the problem. No one wants to do your homework for you.

Comment: i dont know what is your aim?